# Checking if the correct label was clicked?

Tags: c#, list, design-patterns, label

to start of Im not good at programming and I am completely new to it. With that said, I am trying to make a game, where a pattern of labels show up (by the speciffic labels changing colors), and then the user has to click that speciffic pattern after it has been shown. I have already made the pattern show, and put into a list. The problem I now have is how I am going to check if the correct label was licked, acording to the random pattern that has been made. Sorry if my code seems clumsy, but here it is (sorry that there are no commemts yet also):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Spil
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        Label[] labelArray;
        int turn = 1;
        int lives = 3;
        List<Label> orderList = new List<Label>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            labelArray = new Label []{ label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6, label7, label8, label9 };
        }

        private void DisplayOrder()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < labelArray.Length; i++)
            {
                labelArray[i].BackColor = Color.Blue;
            }

            for (int i = -2; i < turn; i++)
            {
                int chosenNumber = rnd.Next(0, 9);
                labelArray[chosenNumber].BackColor = Color.Green;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                labelArray[chosenNumber].BackColor = Color.Blue;
                orderList.Add(labelArray[chosenNumber]);
            }
        }


        private void Click0(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Click3(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Click4(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Click5(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Click6(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Click7(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Click8(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Click9(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(100);

            t.Elapsed += t_Elapsed;

            t.Start();
        }

        void t_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((System.Timers.Timer)sender).Stop();

            DisplayOrder();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have all your labels registered for the same click event and use the sender parameter to identify the clicked label.

```
for (int i = 0; i < labelArray.Length; i++)
{
    labelArray[i].BackColor = Color.Blue;
    labelArray[i].Click += label_Click;
}

void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string name = ((Label)sender).Name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am not entirely sure what this line does: "string name = ((Label)sender).Name;"

Comment: It helps you get the name of the label that was clicked. E.g. Label1

Comment: Im sorry, but I still do not understand how I am supposed to check if the label that is being clicked, is a part of the label pattern.

Comment: @Neebz Assuming that labelArray is your pattern, you could do this `labelArray.Contains((Label)sender)` to check if the clicked label is within the array

Comment: No, the pattern is saved in the "orderList", and it is also very important for the game, that you have to click the first label in the order, and then the second and third.... and so on, so that the same label can be used multiple times in the pattern, just on different indexes. The labelArray is just the collection of labels that can take part in the pattern, not actually the pattern itself.

Comment: @Neebz your problem was that you were not able to identify the label that was clicked. I have shown you how to identify the label. The rest is your game logic. If you face any other issues, please feel free to post another question with more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the Click even for each individual label,you can find the events tab here with the properties tab (in case you didn't know).Simply lick your label in the designer and navigate to the label_click event and double click it.

[image: Events tab]